# Steps to get my digitizer to work in Chrome OS

Tags: linux-kernel, google-chrome-os

I have a digitizer that functions as a HID absolute pointing device. It functions properly in Ubuntu 14.04, but doesn't work in Chrome OS. However, if I boot the chromebook into developer mode, I can see the device showing up, and I can capture input from the USB device.

I would have assumed that since Chrome OS supports external USB mice that this digitizer should work. Does this mean that the kernel used in Chrome OS uses an altered modules for HID devices? (The device uses the stock usbhid driver)

I'm not really sure where to start with this... do I need to write a custom driver to support the device, or do I need to alter the firmware of the device to conform to Chrome OS's implementation of HID?

Comment: Apparently, Chrome OS uses an older driver version, or did not include the driver for your device (whatever it is) in its kernel configuration.

Comment: My device uses the stock hid drivers in the kernel and doesn't require a device specific driver. I'm wondering why something like that would have changed between the two OS's and if Chrome OS specifically blocks absolute HID devices.

Comment: Does "I can capture input" mean that it *actually* works in developer mode?

Comment: It doesn't work in developer mode. The information coming over the wire from the device, captured by USB mon, looks just fine. I feel like some higher level process doesn't like it, for whatever reason.

Comment: It's likely that some kernel or X drivers is not enabled in Chrome OS.